# Including Header files in c++ of STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class Like this

```
/*class.h*/

class MClass
{
 public:
   MClass(std::vector<int> number);

}
```

And

```
/* class.cpp */
#include <vector>
#inclue "class.h"
MClass::MClass(std::vector<int> number)
{
  // Do Something
}
```

And it is not compiled if I do not add `#include <vector>` in the header file
Is this behaviour normal or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should include `<vector>` in your header.  And then you should include your class's header in your cpp file.

You can't compile your cpp file without your class header.  So it's normal to include your class header - there's no way around it.  Also, it's normal to include only what is needed in your header so it doesn't introduce unnecessary dependencies in code that use your header.  In this case, given your member function signature, you are required to include `<vector>` in your header.

Comment: Should I include it bot in *.cpp and *.h files?

Comment: You **need** to include it in your header (see the last sentence in my answer).  By including your class' header in you cpp file, you automatically get the `<vector>` include in your cpp file also.

Comment: In some cas I made exactly reverse.. I included `someheader.h` and then `class.h` in `class.cpp` file no includes in header file.. The header had a dependency of a structure in `someheader.h` file. It compiled well as `someheader.h` was included before `class.h`.But it doesn't work in this case

Comment: It looks like your edited code should work.  But it's wrong.  Because anyone else who tries to include you header.h will get a compile error.  It's normal to include your class' header.h **first** in a cpp file specifically so you can make sure it compiles standalone w/o other includes.

Comment: Is it good practice to have  #include statements in header files. If so where to add before #ifndef or after #ifndef which is good practice ?

Comment: Read the third and fourth sentence of the second paragraph in my answer.  Include guards should surround **everything** in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

class.cpp should #include "class.h"

class.h should #include <vector>

Comment: Updated. I had included #include "class.h"?In some other case Only if I included `someheader.h` in class.cpp the structures included worked fine in class.h file?Is it specific with stl libraries?

Comment: You must #include <vector> in any file that needs to make use of it.

Comment: Your cpp file must include your .h file, so it will also inherit the includes too.

Comment: In your edited example - the cpp file has included the .h and vector - but the .h file has not included vector, so your program will probably not work.  The vector include needs to be in the .h or both